# Rigging an extendable tentacle

Tags: rigging

Hey guys I'm trying to rig some robotic hoses that need the ability to extend to pretty much any length. Imagine something like [Doc Ock's tentacles](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/vsbattles/images/4/4e/Doctor_Octopus_%28Otto_Octavius%29.png/revision/latest?cb=20171012123626) but with the ability to extend themselves. Just to clarify I don't mean they need stretch. I mean they need to extend out from their base. I have some pretty decent experience with rigging, but this one is perplexing me.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could go about this?

Comment: You mean more little sections added as the arm extends?

Comment: Not exactly. Lets pretend I wanted to rig literally [this](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/inspectorgadget/images/5/56/Gadget_Hand.png/revision/latest?cb=20150223223048) instead. All i want is to be able to pull out the hand and have a very long hose connected to it. Do you have any ideas as to how I could go about that?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using Spline Ik and Bendy bones. Here is the result 
[image]
1. Create the bones for your tentacle.
[image]

2. Under the armature settings in display, select B-Bone
   [image]
3. Enter Edit Mode, select each bone and change the segments for it. Note more segments equals a smoother transition.
   [image]
4. Create a Bezier Curve, select the bent handle and scale it to 0 in the y-axis to straighten it. Subdivide it to add as many control points as you want
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmMs8.jpg
5. Align the Curve with the bones.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdWem.jpg
6. Enter Pose Mode, Select the last bone, and add a Spline IK constraint to it. Select the curve and change the chain length to the number of segments the Bendy Bone has.
7. Parent the Bones to the mesh. You can now hide the bones.
   8.Select each part of the spline and press <kbd>ctrl + h</kbd> and choose **Hook to new object**
   Note: I added a subdivision surface modifier on the mesh above the armature to get clean deformation.

Comment: I appreciate the in depth demonstration, but doesn't this just stretch the mesh rather than have more of the tube come out? As in if I wanted to make it appear that Inspector Gadget's hand could extend to a football field's length and I used this method I would just get an incredibly stretched tube with stretched textures wouldn't I? I'm looking for a way to extend Gadget's hand with a seemingly endless supply of hose rather than a stretching hose (even if that means storing a ridiculously long hose inside of his mesh until it comes out)

Comment: I’ve used this technique with a rope that could stretch forever and it didn’t stretch.